# Re-sizing window multiple times

Tags: powershell, resize, width

Wondering what you would type to edit the height, width, buffer size in powershell? I know you can edit the program to do it but I need to have it in a script.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the console size use `$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize`. In order to change the buffer size use `$Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize`. Mind the proper order of changes, e.g. the buffer size cannot be smaller than the console size, even temporary.

Take a look at the script [Set-ConsoleSize.ps1](https://github.com/nightroman/PowerShelf/blob/master/Set-ConsoleSize.ps1). It is ready to use for changing console size by arrow keys. Take a look at the code, all the answers on how "to edit the height, width, buffer size" are there.